# Algebraic Geometry - Blowup

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I am starting to study for my Msc dissertation and i want / have to study the Blowing up transformation in algebraic geometry. I know little about algebraic geometry but i'm a stubborn learner and so i can make it in the end. I would like to know some good references / books so to understand it intuitively and then more strictly.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Section IV.2 of Eisenbud-Harris "Geometry of Schemes" is about blowing up.  I was one of the proofreaders for that section :)

Answer (score 2):

An elementary and extremely detailed account of this is given in the book Brieskorn, Knörrer: *Plane Algebraic Curves*.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but could you please indicate me the pages because i cannot find it in the index and the book is big enough.

Comment: @Mitsos I do not have the book with me now, but I recall that there are about 200 pages on the topic.

Comment: The topic is called "quadratic transformation" in the table of contents, but the term "blowing up a point" does occur in my index as on p. 462.

Comment: The discussion in Brieskorn may be only for plane curves.  There is a nice discussion also in Shafarevich's Basic Algebraic Geometry, 1974, in both two and higher dimensions, in sections II.4, IV.3, and VI.2, where he uses blowups (sigma processes) to analyze birational maps of surfaces, and to construct a non projective 3 dimensional variety.

Comment: Mumford also gives a precise but intuitive description related to projecting subvarieties of projective space, on p.74 of Alg. Geom. I: Proj. varieties.